# JQGrid treegrid check all child rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am new to JQ Grid and I am using TreeGrid feature of JQGrid for ASP.NET MVC.

I have a checkbox column in the grid and I would like to do:

a) When the checkbox in parent row is checked (or unchecked), check/uncheck all children row's checkboxes (toggle behavior)

b) Also when a child row's checkbox is checked (or unchecked) -check/uncheck all the parent's row's checkboxes

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you could share more info about checkboxes and their ids/classnames or a structure which is available in the grid.

Comment: Are you prompting of check all option or multi select ?